# How to create posts ordered by date

Tags: php, database, pagination, sql-order-by

im creating pagination(it is not complete, but only most important part i think) for my website, everything is working good but it shows posts from the oldest it means oldest are on top ... but i need the newest posts on top on first page of my pagination

this is my pagination script

```
        include('mysql.php');   
        $tbl_name="posts";      
        $adjacents = 3;

       /* 
       First get total number of rows in data table. 
       */
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM posts";
        $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
        $total_pages = $total_pages[num]; 

       /* Setup vars for query. */  
        $targetpage = "index.php";  
        $limit = 6;                                 
        $page = $_GET['page'];

        if($page) 
            $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          
        else
            $start = 3; 

       /* Get data. */
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT $start, $limit";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

       /* Setup page vars for display. */
        if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  
        $prev = $page - 1;                          
        $next = $page + 1;                          
        $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      
        $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;
```

When i use

```
        $result = mysql_safe_query('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC');
```

it will show posts from the newest to oldest but pagination will fail

Im still learning php so for every advice or solution really thanks

Comment: Do you know that your ORDER BY query doesn't have the LIMIT clause?

Comment: Thank you, i started think about it diferently, now it is fixed ...